# How to check if radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I'm prefacing this question by saying my knowledge of JavaScript is very limited and I'm not a developer. I've been asked to help build a price calculator wizard for my company.

I found some code from W3 Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp) to create a form that checks if each input field is empty. I'd like to make changes to the code to check if a radio button in each group has been selected.

I'm not sure how to change this line of code

```
if (y[i].value == "")
```

to make it check if a radio button has been selected.

Below is one of my radio groups and the script to check if an input field is empty.

If you want to see the complete code, please go to the W3 Schools link above.

```
 <div class="tab">Option 1:
    <p><input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" oninput="this.className = ''"><label for="male">Male</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" oninput="this.className = ''"><label for="female">Female</label></p>
  </div>      

function validateForm() {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
          // If a field is empty...
          if (y[i].value == "") {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].className += " invalid";
            // and set the current valid status to false:
            valid = false;
          }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
      }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

All I'm asking is how do I change the link of code to check if the radio buttons are checked instead of checking if the input fields contain a value.

Comment: your question is ambiguous. What you want ?? all radio buttons are checked or validate some value??

Comment: @tuhin47 you are very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check all radio buttons are checked:

```js
const radioButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]'));

function checkChecked(){
  console.log(radioButtons.every(button => button.checked));
}

radioButtons.forEach(button => button.onchange = checkChecked);
```

```html
<input type=radio />
<input type=radio />
<input type=radio />
<input type=radio />
<input type=radio />
```

LVL 2: Check all groups of radiobuttons has at least one checked:

```js
const groupNames = ['group1', 'group2', 'group3'];
const radioButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]'));
    
function checkChecked(){
  console.log(groupNames.every(group =>
    document.querySelector(`input[name=${group}]:checked`)
  ));
}

radioButtons.forEach(button => button.onchange = checkChecked);
```

```html
<input name="group1" type=radio />
<input name="group1" type=radio />
<input name="group1" type=radio />
<br/>
<input name="group2" type=radio />
<input name="group2" type=radio />
<br/>
<input name="group3" type=radio />
<input name="group3" type=radio />
```

Comment: @mplungjan I answer straight to question 'how to make it validate if all radio buttons are checked', not to 'how validate all groups of radiobuttons has some checked button'

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @StevenErickson I edit my answer, now this is what you wanted?

Comment: No, not at all. I am asking how do I change the line of code "if (y[i].value == "") {" to check if the radio buttons are checked instead of checking if the form field has a value.

Comment: @StevenErickson No, Steve, you asked 'how to make it validate if all radio buttons are checked' and first variation of my answer gave the answer to this question.
`y[i].value == ""` for radiobuttons you need change to `if(y[i].checked)`.